# How to auto switch DNS settings while connect to different WiFi?

Tags: network, wifi, dns

I have totally different DNS settings when I am at work and when I am at home. I was wondering can I change my MacBook Pro's DNS settings automatically when I connect to different WiFi.

I did a lot of searches, I made a custom Location called Home in the network settings. And I set my Home DNS settings under this profile. And a default profile called Automatic I let the computer automatically get DNS settings.

After that, I can change my DNS settings through:

```
networksetup -switchtolocation Home
```

It is very close to my demand. But I hope I can find a smarter way, If I figure out a method If I connect to a WiFi called "Home", and then execute the command automatically, It will be excellent.

### 20200819 Update

I find an automation tool called [Hammerspoon](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/), so I can assign a shortcut to switch different Locations using the command.

Although I did not find a direct way, but Hammerspoon is great and powerful. I tried to watch Wifi change using Hammerspoon, but it remains a little problem, so I open an issue [here](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/issues/2434)

Comment: Are you using custom DNS, not that advertised by your router?

Comment: @Tetsujin I use a Custom DNS setting.

Comment: OK, otherwise Automatic ought to just work. idk how to set automatic but custom DNS, different for 2 places.

Comment: WiFi ≠ Networks.  What I mean by that is DNS is related to the Network.  When people refer to WiFi names like "Home" they're referring to the SSID being broadcast.  You can have several SSIDs  (i.e "Home, Kids, and HouseGuests) all on the same network.  So, to be clear, do you want different DNS settings per WiFi SSID or per different network?

Comment: I've posted an answer that is free and will save you from spending $36 on Keyboard Maestro.

Answer (score 5):

**[Update for MacOS Sonoma]**: The Sonoma System Settings app (and maybe other versions after High Sierra) have removed the 'Location' option from the UI, but it's still there via CLI. Start by creating a new location with `networksetup -createlocation Home populate`, then switch to it with `networksetup -switchtolocation Home`, and change your DNS settings to what you need; to go back to the default location, you can run `networksetup -switchtolocation Automatic`

---

You do not need to use a third-party *application* to accomplish your goal.

When **Wi-Fi** connects to a *network* the following *file*, among others, is modified:

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
```

**[Update for MacOS Sonoma]** As of 9 Feb 2024, Sonoma (and maybe other versions after High Sierra) don't seem to update `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist` anymore. However, `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist` (for most networks), and `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.wifi.known-networks.plist` (for hotspots) are suitable replacements. See [this Github thread](https://github.com/rimar/wifi-location-changer/issues/23) for more info.

You can use a *User* **Launch Agent** with a **WatchPaths** *key* to know when the target *file* is modified and execute your *script* accordingly.

The following is an example of how to accomplish the goal and is using **SkyNet** as the **SSID** of the **Wi-Fi** *network*.

Using `networksetup` to get the current **Wi-Fi** *network*, the following *example* **shell script** *code* is used and saved as e.g. `/usr/local/bin/detect-wifi-change`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

[[ $(networksetup -getairportnetwork en0) == "Current Wi-Fi Network: SkyNet" ]] && say "connected to skynet" && networksetup -switchtolocation Home
```

In the example *code* above, when **Wi-Fi** is connected to **SkyNet** it simply says it's "connected to skynet", and you would replace **SkyNet** in the `$(...)` portion of the *command* with your target **SSID**, and replace the `say "connected to skynet"` *command* with the `networksetup -switchtolocation Home` *command* as shown in your question.

**[Update for MacOS Sonoma]** `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.wifi.known-networks.plist` seems to change for reasons other than WiFi reconnecting based on my own anecdotal evidence (eg. when changing WiFi settings); to only change network locations when necessary, you should use something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(networksetup -getairportnetwork en0) == "Current Wi-Fi Network: SkyNet" ]]
then
        if ! [[ $(networksetup -getcurrentlocation) == "Home" ]]
        then
                networksetup -switchtolocation Home
                say "Switched to Home network location"
        fi
else
        if ! [[ $(networksetup -getcurrentlocation) == "Automatic" ]]
        then
                networksetup -switchtolocation Automatic
                say "Switched to Automatic network location"
        fi
fi
```

For the **Launch Agent**, in the **Library** of your **Home** *folder* you'd use the following example, saved as, e.g., `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.detect.wifi.change.plist`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.my.detect.wifi.change</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/detect-wifi-change</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist</string>
        <string>/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist</string>
        <string>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.wifi.known-networks.plist</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After saving the **PLIST** *file*, use `launchctl` to `load` it, e.g.:

```bash
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.detect.wifi.change.plist
```

**[Update for macOS Sonoma]**

<sup>Note: You can use the `unload` *verb* with `launchctl` to unload the target **PLIST** *file*.</sup>

Now whenever **Wi-Fi** connects to a different **SSID** the e.g. `/usr/local/bin/detect-wifi-change` is executed and if connected to the target **SSID** the *command* after the `&&` is executed.

---

<sup>Note: The above example was tested and worked under **macOS High Sierra** using my actual **SSID** in place of **SkyNet** in both places in the *script*.</sup>

---

**Related Documentation:**

In **Terminal**, substitute `command` for one of the following:

- `launchd`
- `launchd.plist`
- `launchctl`

You can read the *manual page* for `command`  in **Terminal** by typing `command` and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

**See Also:**

- [Locations feature in more detail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277160/351074)
- [A launchd Tutorial](https://www.launchd.info)
- [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)
- [Technical Note TN2083 Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794)

Comment: Is there a documentation of other possible keys like **WatchPaths** ?

Comment: @anki, See the **Related Documentation:** section of my updated answer.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you for providing such great information.

Answer (score 4):

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) can do this very easily:

[image: Screenshot of Keyboard Maestro]

Set the SSID and Location that you want, and that should do what you want.

Comment: Keyboard Marstro looks cool, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without 3rd party apps. Not that I am cheap about spending $36, but I like to see if there are free, built in ways to do things.   Either way, I upvoted for a good answer.

Comment: I just used a variation of this - Home SSID gets 'home' w/ pi-hole for DNS, *all other* SSID's get 'automatic' with 1.1.1.1 for DNS. Just duplicated the Keyboard Maestro macro and changed 'is connected' to 'is disconnected' and changed network location name to 'automatic' - thanks tj-luoma!