# Automatically run script on login (MacOS 10.15)

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

Because of a small disk I've got an external USB-C SSD drive where I want to move some software projects I'm currently no working on.
To see the outsourced projects in my default projects directory in finder and terminal, I thought of Symlinking the external projects to my default folder. I tried using fswatch to detect changes and automatically Symlink new folders.

```
# watchExternalProjects.sh
fswatch -o /Volumes/SSD/Projects/ | xargs -n1 -I{} ./createSymlinks.sh
```

```
# createSymlinks.sh
cd ~/Projects && find -L . -name . -o -type d -prune -o -type l -exec rm {} +

ln -s /Volumes/SSD/Projects/* ~/Projects/ 2> /dev/null
```

This works, but now I want to automatically start this script on login. I've tried making an Automator App which calls the script and put it in the login items, but the watcher does not stay active but runs only once on login and further changes are not detected.
I've also tried setting up a Launch Agent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/Documents/Files/watchExternalProjects.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This seems not to work.

Any ideas?

### Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/user/Documents/Files/createSymlinks.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/user</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>user</string>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Volumes/SSD/Projects/</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.user.loginscript.stdout</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.user.loginscript.stderr</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This seems to work, maybe the first one also did. But now I'm able to track it down to an "Operation not permitted" error logged in com.user.loginscript.stderr

Comment: For detecting when you plug in an external disk, you can use an **Automator** _Folder Action_ on `/Volumes` or if you want to go the `launchd` route, use a **WatchPaths** _key_ in **PLIST** _file_ of your **Launch Agent**. For the latter, see this answer I wrote for an example: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399490/how-to-auto-switch-dns-settings-while-connect-to-different-wifi/399571#399571

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the advice, I'm trying the WatchPaths key. The Automator Folder Action is not suitable to me, because it does not detect if a folder is deleted.

Comment: Just a quick read on the Edit: section, is the _executable bit_ set on the `createSymlinks.sh` _file_? Also, take a look at the `ProgramArguments` _key_ in the link of my first comment. Its _array_ has two _strings_, `<string>/bin/sh</string>` and the second one points to the _shell script_.

Comment: The script is definitely set executable. The ProgramArguments change results in a "/bin/sh: /Users/user/Documents/Files/createSymlinks: No such file or directory" error

Comment: Does the second _string_ of the _array_ have the _fully qualified pathname_ of the _target file_? You should update your question with the current contents of the `.plist` _file_.

Comment: Yes it has the fully qualified pathname

Comment: In the `.plist` _file_ you have `/Users/user/Documents/Files/createSymlinks.sh`, but in the _error_ it shows `/Users/user/Documents/Files/createSymlinks`, note there is no `.sh` on the _error_.

Comment: I didn't update the entry according to your suggested ProgramArgumentes change. So the version which throws this error is: 
 `<key>ProgramArguments</key> <array> <string>/bin/sh</string> <string>/Users/user/Documents/Files/createSymlinks</string> </array>`

Comment: You need to use the _fully qualified pathname_ of the _target file_, you can't drop the `.sh` _file extension_ because mine didn't have one. I never put a _file extension_ on my `bash` _shell scripts_. If you use the _fully qualified pathname_ does it still _error_?

Comment: Ah didn't get that, but already tried earlier and that throws an "Operation not permitted" error

Comment: Does the following throw an _error_?
`<key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
<string>/bin/sh</string>
<string>/Users/user/Documents/Files/createSymlinks.sh</string>
</array>`

Comment: Yes, Operation not permitted

Comment: If I put the scripts in the same directory as you did here [https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399490/...](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399490/how-to-auto-switch-dns-settings-while-connect-to-different-wifi/399571#399571), the script is permitted but "find" operation within the script is not

Comment: [https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399490/...](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399490/how-to-auto-switch-dns-settings-while-connect-to-different-wifi/399571#399571) the wifi detection does work for me

Comment: Just saying "the wifi detection does work for me" doesn't really tell me anything! The answer I posted in that link works as advertised provided you follow the directions and make the appropriate changes as described. It's running just fine on my system.